# Каким способом лучше всего расположить частицы на фоне секции адаптивного сайта?

Tags: html, css

Есть такой дизайн, где на фоне расположены квадраты, круги, треугольники и кресты в SVG формате (скриншот). Каким способом их грамотнее всего будет располагать? Вручную прописывать каждой position absolute с координатами это бред как по мне. В голову еще идет вариант с фотошопом и созданием бесшового фрагмента, но хотелось бы минимизировать растровую графику на сайте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все же по моему только ручками, бред не бред, но их не так уж и много.Можно Через js динамически создавать div c svg. А в js создать массив с координатами и типом картинки ,Будет типа мини плагин. Фигуры разбросаны все ж с неким смыслом. По моему других вариантов и нет, а рисовать огромный фрагмент в фотошопе ,тоже будет много разных кусков.

Comment: @ Андрей Солуянов, поделитесь, как бы Вы свое решение поддерживали?

Comment: canvas лучше или svg в смеси с javascript

Comment: Если все фигуры векторные, то не проще ли SVG и использовать в качестве фона?

Comment: @ UModeL я тоже думал над этим вариантом. Но как это грамотно реализовывать на всех устройствах, чтобы эти картинки не были очень большие или очень маленькие?

Comment: Собственно, так и сделал, расположил значки в иллюстраторе на сером фоне и экспортировал , вроде нормально выглядит